# Robot Framework :- Cannot Open Chrome from Existing Chrome Profile

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am trying to Learn Robot Framework. I have already worked on Selenium Webdriver. I was trying to open the Chrome Browser from an Exiting Profile using Create Webdriver Keyword. However i am not able to do . It Seems that Robot Framework Opens a new Chrome Profile Everytime. 
Here is the Code that i got after goggling, but this is not opening Chrome from the User data folder that i prefer. Any Suggestions or Ideas this can be achieved.

```
    Open Chrome Using Create WebDriver Keyword
[Tags]  chrome
${options}=  Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()  sys, selenium.webdriver
${options.add_argument}=  Set Variable  --allow-running-insecure-content
${options.add_argument}=  Set Variable  --disable-web-security
${options.add_argument}=  Set Variable  user-data-dir = /Users/myName/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data
Create WebDriver  Chrome  chrome_options=${options}
go to  {URL}
```

# Close Browser

Answer (score 2):

To add arguments, call the *add_argument* method of the *ChromeOptions* object. Note that you need to escape the '=' in the --user-data-dir argument or Robot Framework will look for an argument called '--user-data-dir' and fail. When testing this I noticed that a profile will be created in the location specified if it does not exist.

```
Open Chrome Using Create WebDriver Keyword
    ${options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    --allow-running-insecure-content
    Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    --disable-web-security
    Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    --user-data-dir\=/Users/myName/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data
    Create WebDriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${options}
    Go To    https://stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: Thanks you for your quick Reply. Its working to perfection now. Appreciate your time .. :)

Comment: Thanks for tip to add \ before =. This solved error: `Calling method 'add_argument' failed: TypeError: add_argument() got an unexpected keyword argument '--user-data-dir'`