# No log entries found for BrowserMobProxy With Robot Framework

Tags: python, python-2.7, robotframework, browsermob-proxy

I have written this script in robot framework.

```
Set Selenium Implicit Wait    10
## Init BrowserMob Proxy
${file}    Join Path    ${EXECDIR}    browsermob-proxy-2.1.4    bin    browsermob-proxy.bat
File Should Exist    ${file}
Start Local Server    ${file}

# Create dedicated proxy on BrowserMob Proxy
${BrowserMob_Proxy}=    Create Proxy

# Configure Webdriver to use BrowserMob Proxy
${options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
Call Method    ${options}    add_argument      --proxy\=${BrowserMob_Proxy}
Create WebDriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${options}

New Har    google
Go To    ${PAGE_URL}
Title Should Be    Google
${har}=     Get Har As Json
Create File     ${EXECDIR}${/}file.har     ${har}

Close All Browsers
Stop Local Server
```

But when I try to validate through HAR Analyzer, it return error saying No log entries found in the file.

> Errors found when processing the HAR file:
>   No log entries found in the file.

Result of the har:

```
{"log": {"comment": "", "entries": [], "version": "1.2", "pages": [{"pageTimings": {"comment": ""}, "comment": "", "title": "google", "id": "google", "startedDateTime": "2017-03-23T10:26:27.317+08:00"}], "creator": {"comment": "", "version": "2.1.4", "name": "BrowserMob Proxy"}}}
```

Comment: Does the browser part work? I.e. Is the Google page successfully loaded? Is google only available via the proxy or is a direct connection also possible?

Comment: The browser successfully done and can access google. Both can acess google.

Comment: if I try using --proxy-server then I cant access the page.

Answer (score 0):

From the description it is clear that the URL you're trying to reach is both accessible with and without the proxy. The purpose of the proxy is to server as an means to record/manipulate traffic between the browser and it's destination.

The below code example has been tested and confirmed to work. It is a variation found in this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38226102/robot-framework-cannot-open-chrome-from-existing-chrome-profile). The only difference I see with your example is the `--proxy` that should be `--proxy-server`

```
Open Chrome Using Create WebDriver Keyword
        ${options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
        Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    --proxy-server\=localhost:8080
        Create WebDriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${options}
        Go To    https://stackoverflow.com
```

After some discussion in chat we derived that in addition to the above a proxy port can be set using the following construct:

```
&{port}    Create Dictionary    port=8084
${BrowserMob_Proxy}=    Create Proxy    ${port}
```

With the knowledge that the proxy is running on the same host as BrowserMob, which is known, and the proxy port is known, the ChromeOptions can now be specified:

```
Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    --proxy-server\=localhost:8084
```

This can then be combined with the HAR generating code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer . I have tried with that option but it returns error on chrome. 

`This site can’t be reached

The webpage at https://stackoverflow.com/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED`

Comment: Have you verified that the proxy is working when configured directly in your browser?

Comment: reach this error`This site can’t be reached

The webpage at http://localhost:8080/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES`

Comment: The localhost address is the address of my own proxy. This should be `${BrowserMob_Proxy}` in your example. It is only the parameter name that you should change into `--proxy-server` with the emphasis on the `-server` part that is missing in your own example.

Comment: Looks like the port is not configured properly.

Comment: If this solves your issue, can you mark it as answered?

Comment: Issue still not solve. still figuring out how to generate port.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138913/discussion-between-a-kootstra-and-wan-mohd-payed).