# How to run automation test via chromedriver by local user to inherit user's cache/cookie?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I'm running robot framework to test web (test suite is working OK)
But I'm facing with cache. The is NO cache if I run the test by chromedriver (Browser Notification: Chrome is being controlled by automated test software.)

My expectation: run automation and use cache from local user (my login use for example)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it is clearer what your problem is.

Comment: if i understand you correct, you want to use a "user profile". this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480717/load-chrome-profile-using-selenium-webdriver-using-java

Comment: Thank you, I totally found the solution on this link (for exactly Robot Framework): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38226102/robot-framework-cannot-open-chrome-from-existing-chrome-profile